# Concatenate a List into String in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

I am learning how to code, so I am sorry if this question has already been answered in some way. But I feel completely stuck for some reason. I have the following code.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pattern = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    def pattern_as_string(self):
       self.pattern_new = ''.join(self.pattern)
       return self.pattern_new
```

I then execute in Python:

```
>>> test = Test()
>>> test.pattern_as_string
```

The goal here is to concatenate a list into a string, and have that returned by a seperate function. I am expecting as output: 'abc' but instead I get:
"bound method Test.pattern_as_string of **main**.Test object at 0x7f113080d630>>"

What am I doing wrong? I have a feeling I am outputting a location instead of the actual string; but I don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: You're not calling the method. You're calling the reference of the method. Try: `test.pattern_as_string()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test.pattern_as_string` is a method, you should call it:
`test.pattern_as_string()`. This should fix the problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: functions inside of Classes are called methods. Otherwise this is the answer you're looking for.